# Twin Primes that are Sophie Germain Primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Suppose $p$ is a prime  such that $p + 2$ is also prime, and nothing else is known about $p$.

Is there any reason to think that this affects the probability that $p$ is also a Sophie Germain prime?  Other than the fact that $p \pmod 6$ would have to be $5$?
It would seem that the answer has to be no, but I have some perplexing
computational results that I would like to account for.

Comment: What exactly is your numeric evidence?

Comment: It's not just mod 6; there is a bias modulo every small prime.  For instance, mod 5, a prime p is equal to 1,2,3,4 mod 5, and needs to avoid 2 mod 5 to have any chance to be a Sophie Germain prime (unless it actually is 2).  But if p is a twin prime, it avoids 3 mod 5 (if it isn't actually 3), which slightly raises the chance that it is equal to 2 mod 5 instead.

Comment: The asymptotics from the Hardy-Littlewood prime tuple conjecture can be used to predict the number of tuples of the form p, p+2, 2p+1 that are simultaneously prime, and this can lead to a prediction of the precise bias in the probability that 2p+1 is prime if one conditions on the event that p+2 is prime also.

Comment: See COMMENTS by John W. Nicholson, on Dec 14 2013 at http://oeis.org/A168421 .